# How to get resources from a referenced project in VisualSstudio

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, embedded-resource

I have a project which uses a tinyMCE editor in a windows form app. Within the same solution there is a class library which contains a resource file with a zip file which contains the tinyMCE editor and the scripts for the editor.

Within the main project, I need to be able to access the resource file from the class library and then retrieve the zipped up file from this resource to use within the project.

When I have this information I can then unzip the file and put it into a filestream where my user can then write to the editor and change what it contains. After they have manipulated the editor my code will then zip the newly edited version of the tinyMCE editor and the scripts and then overwrite the old version of this zipped file.

I am running on c# 4.0 currently and so far I have this code for attempting to access the resource file but it doesn't seem to be working...?

```
     var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        foreach(var resourceName in assembly.GetManifestResourceNames())
        {
            string theResources = resourceName;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution that is probably easier than the one you are trying now:

1. Create a Resources file, or use the existing if you already have one;
2. Add the zip file to the resources;
3. Set the `Access Modifier` property to `Public`. This will make the Resources visible outside your assembly;
4. Reference the resources using the full class name of the resources, something like:

   ```
   byte[] zipFile = ClassLibrary1.Properties.Resources.my_zip_file;
   ```